# Laravel-Class Method with Reflected Parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I usually use parameters like this:

```
public function test($parameter)
{
 echo 'Parameter value: ' . $parameter;
}
```

While looking at [laravel service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#introduction) I see this code.

```
 public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
```

According to the documentation it uses reflection.But i dont understand.

I dont know how the parameter `UserRepository $users` works. Is that an alias or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called type-hinting and is used to inject dependencies in a constructor or to validate the right type of argument is passed to a function. The injection simply means that if the class is called with the `make` method, Laravel will automatically provide an instance of the class required by your constructor.

For example if you have a function `public function something(string $something)` it would throw an error if any other type than a `String` is passed to this function, making sure the right data is used.

From the laravel documentation:

> Alternatively, and importantly, you may "type-hint" the dependency in the constructor of a class that is resolved by the container, including controllers, event listeners, queue jobs, middleware, and more. In practice, this is how most of your objects should be resolved by the container.
>   For example, you may type-hint a repository defined by your application in a controller's constructor. The repository will automatically be resolved and injected into the class:

Comment: This is the anserwer :). + 1

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a great service container and it makes all dependency injections, so you don't need to pass a class a parameter, laravel do it for you.

without container you have to pass this parameter

```
class A {
public $foo;

public function __construct (Foo $foo){
   $this->foo
}

$classA = new A((new Foo))
```

When laravel encounter with these classes, it `resolves` them.

Also you can define manually these classes using `singleton()` or `bind()` methods

```
$this->app->singleton('FooBar', function($app)
{
    return new FooBar($app['SomethingElse']);
});
```

Or you may use interfaces. You can bind implemented class for to the interface and laravel when encounter with that interfance, it will resolve as you wish

```
$this->app->bind('App\ICacheManager', 'App\RedisManager');

public $redis;

public function __contruct(ICacheManager $redis){
  $this->redis = $redis;
}
```

for more further check out [laravel service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#basic-usage)